# Add a count column of non-unique identifier in reshape2 code

Tags: r, reshape2

I would like to add a column to a data frame I altered using reshape2 that is simply the number of times each email address (a non-unique identifier) appeared before I reshaped the data frame. My data frame includes an email address identifier and several numeric values, like this:

```
Email              | Val1 | Val2 |  Val3
blah@blahmail.com     1     2       3
blah@blahmail.com     3     5       2
blah@blahmail.com     8     5       2
j@blahmail.com        7     4       8
a@blahmail.com        3     6       1
a@blahmail.com        3     5       5
```

I have used the following code to sum the relevant numeric entries by email address so that I have one row per email address.

Here is the code I used to reshape my dataframe:

```
library(reshape2)
meltTest <- melt(df, id.vars = "email")
dcastTest <- dcast(meltTest, email ~ variable, fun.aggregate = sum, 
na.rm = TRUE)
```

I have attempted to add an alternative function (fun.aggregate) and have also tried "margins." I realize that tidyr is also an alternative, but it is difficult to use with my non-unique identifier. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It might help if you also provided the desired output so that possible solutions can be tested and verified,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming meltTest is the dataframe you have shown above, you can use the `dplyr` package to complete both the steps in one go like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df_new <- meltTest %>% 
group_by(Email) %>% 
summarise(TotVal1 = sum(Val1, na.rm = TRUE), TotVal2 = sum(Val2, na.rm = TRUE), TotVal3 = sum(Val3, na.rm = TRUE), TotCount = length(Email))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!